# Find objects of a specific type in an object graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, object, recursion

Given an object instance, how can I recurse its members (i.e. the whole object graph) for an object of a specific type, or one that inherits from a specific type?

For example, I want to find all objects in session that may have deep indirect references to System.Web.UI.Control.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly how to do it but i'm quite sure you have to use **Reflection** to iterate over all properties of an object. Google and you will most likely find an example. Like this one http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/474/how-to-iterate-through-all-properties-of-a-class/

With that you can probably figure out how to do the recursion yourself.